# Naming of .tar in maven deploy

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, artifactory

I have maven project that should build me a .jar file. Lets call it test.jar
After that I want to deploy .tar archive(contains test.jar and some other files) with specific name, server-bundle.tar to an artifactory.

I'm trying to do that through plugins, but I want specific name of final .tar. Maven though make it either from artifact or finalName the same as .jar file name.

How should I do pom for Maven, so it:

1) Build test.jar with the name of the artifact

2) Package server-bundle.tar with test.jar and some files

3) Deploy it to artifactory with the project version server-bundle-1.0.tar

Here is my pom file:

```
<groupId>com.my.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorId>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorId>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>test.main.MainClass</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>server-bundle</finalName>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/test.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>server-bundle</finalName>
                        <file>${project.build.directory}/server-bundle.tar</file>
                        <generatePom>false</generatePom>
                        <pomFile>pom.xml</pomFile>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <outputFileNameMapping>server-bundle.tar</outputFileNameMapping>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
        <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.18</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>releases</name>
        <url>https://localhost/artifactory/release-local</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

and my configuration file:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>bundle</id>
<formats>
    <format>tar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>environment</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>file1.txt</include>
            <include>file2.txt</include>
            <include>file3.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>${project.artifactId}.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Comment: What kind of tar file name you are currently getting exactly? server-bundle-all.tar? server-bundle-bundle.tar?

Comment: I'm getting test.jar and server-bundle-bundle.tar on the local PC.

But when I look in the artifactory - there are test-1.0.jar and test-1.0-bundle.tar.

Comment: Ok, so add <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId> to second execution of maven assembly plugin (inside configuration tags). Then the tar file name should be server-bundle.tar. If that is not the one you want it to be, then just change the finalName in the same execution

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for appendAssemblyId, but thats not an original request.

I told about renaming .tar file when deploying to the artifactory. And I can't use <finalName> in execution part..  


I'm seeing in log:  [INFO] Installing C:\test\target\server-bundle.tar to C:\test\1.0\test-1.0-bundle.tar

So install plugin renames my artifact just before deploying,,

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your request. But you can't rename the files how they are named in a Maven repository cause that naming schema is the foundation of being findable by coordinates. Furthermore the `<finalName>..</finalName>` will only name the artifact in the `target` directory but not the name which is used in the remote repository like Artifactory/Nexus etc.